# Adding another Javascript filtering section to working code

Tags: javascript

@Developer helped me with getting a filter system working using JavaScript. I'm having trouble with the last part of the JavaScript under "Default". What I'm trying to do is add another checkbox group called "Category" to add one more additional filter, but I'm not sure how to code the 'else if' part. Below is my working code. I dont want to change anything aside from getting the new group working. Can someone help please? Thanks!

```js
const filterCheckboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.filter-checkbox');
const colorCheckboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.color-checkbox');
const sizeCheckboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.size-checkbox');
const priceCheckboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.price-checkbox');
const categoryCheckboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.category-checkbox');
const filterables = document.querySelectorAll('.filterable');

function getCheckedValues(checkboxes) {
  return Array.from(checkboxes)
    .filter(checkbox => checkbox.checked)
    .map(checkbox => checkbox.value);
}

function updateFilter() {
 let level = 0;

 const colorChecked = getCheckedValues(colorCheckboxes);
 // If there is any Color Checkbox
 if (colorChecked.length) level++;

 const sizeChecked = getCheckedValues(sizeCheckboxes);
 // If there is any Size Checkbox
 if (sizeChecked.length) level++;

 const priceChecked = getCheckedValues(priceCheckboxes);
 // If there is any price Checkbox
 if (priceChecked.length) level++;
    
const categoryChecked = getCheckedValues(categoryCheckboxes);
 // If there is any category Checkbox
 if (categoryChecked.length) level++;

 if (!level) {
   filterables.forEach(filterable => {
     filterable.style.display = 'block';
   })
   return;
 }

 filterables.forEach(filterable => {
   const colors = filterable.dataset.colors.split(' ');
   switch (level) {
     case 1:
       // if this case, it means that only one filter is selected
       if (colorChecked.includes(colors[0]) || sizeChecked.includes(colors[1]) || priceChecked.includes(colors[2]) || categoryChecked.includes(colors[3])) {
          filterable.style.display = 'block';
       } else {
          filterable.style.display = 'none';
       }
       break;
     case 3:
       // Case 3 means that all filters are selected
       if (colorChecked.includes(colors[0]) && sizeChecked.includes(colors[1]) && priceChecked.includes(colors[2]) && priceChecked.includes(colors[3])) {
          filterable.style.display = 'block';
       } else {
         filterable.style.display = 'none';
       }
       break;
     default:
       // Default means that two filters are seleted
       if (colorChecked.length >= 1 && sizeChecked.length >= 1) {
         if (colorChecked.includes(colors[0]) && sizeChecked.includes(colors[1])) {
            filterable.style.display = 'block';
         } else {
            filterable.style.display = 'none';
         }
        } else if (colorChecked.length >= 1 && priceChecked.length >= 1) {
           if (colorChecked.includes(colors[0]) && priceChecked.includes(colors[2])) {
                filterable.style.display = 'block';
           } else {
                filterable.style.display = 'none';
           }
         } else {
           if (sizeChecked.includes(colors[1]) && priceChecked.includes(colors[2])) {
              filterable.style.display = 'block';
            } else {
                filterable.style.display = 'none';
            }
          }
          break;
        }
      });
}

filterCheckboxes.forEach(checkbox => {
   checkbox.addEventListener('change', updateFilter);
});

updateFilter(); // initial filter based on default checkbox state
```

```html
<div>
    <h3>Color</h3>
    <label><input type="checkbox" class="filter-checkbox color-checkbox" value="red">Red</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" class="filter-checkbox color-checkbox" value="green">Green</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" class="filter-checkbox color-checkbox" value="blue">Blue</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h3>Size</h3>
    <label><input type="checkbox" class="filter-checkbox size-checkbox" value="small">Small</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" class="filter-checkbox size-checkbox" value="medium">Medium</label><label>
      <input type="checkbox" class="filter-checkbox size-checkbox" value="large">Large</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h3>Price</h3>
    <label><input type="checkbox" class="filter-checkbox price-checkbox" value="10">$10</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" class="filter-checkbox price-checkbox" value="20">$20</label><label>
      <input type="checkbox" class="filter-checkbox price-checkbox" value="30">$30</label>
  </div>
    <div>
    <h3>Category</h3>
    <label><input type="checkbox" class="filter-checkbox category-checkbox" value="a">A</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" class="filter-checkbox category-checkbox" value="b">B</label><label>
      <input type="checkbox" class="filter-checkbox category-checkbox" value="c">C</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <br>
    <hr>
    <h1>Filtered Result</h1>
    <div class="filterable" data-colors="blue large 30 b">Product One</div>
    <div class="filterable" data-colors="green small 10 a">Product Two</div>
    <div class="filterable" data-colors="red medium 20 c">Product Three</div>
    <div class="filterable" data-colors="red large 30 a">Product Four</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: btw, why not use different `data-` attributes for different filtertypes? if not, how do you distigush between same value for different purposses?

Comment: I know you mention that you don't want to change anything besides solving the problem at hand. However, that code isn't scalable as you are experiencing and is going to constantly cause headaches.

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify it a bit by first making a list of items that should appear (`filtered`) and filtering out the colors that were not checked, then the sizes that were not checked, etc.

Once you have the filtered list, you can update the display css prop.

```js
const filterCheckboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.filter-checkbox');
const colorCheckboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.color-checkbox');
const sizeCheckboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.size-checkbox');
const priceCheckboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.price-checkbox');
const categoryCheckboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.category-checkbox');
const filterables = document.querySelectorAll('.filterable');

function getCheckedValues(checkboxes) {
  return Array.from(checkboxes)
    .filter(checkbox => checkbox.checked)
    .map(checkbox => checkbox.value);
}

function updateFilter() {
 const colorChecked = getCheckedValues(colorCheckboxes);
 const sizeChecked = getCheckedValues(sizeCheckboxes);
 const priceChecked = getCheckedValues(priceCheckboxes);
 const categoryChecked = getCheckedValues(categoryCheckboxes);
 
 let filtered = Array.from(filterables); // make a copy
 
 if (colorChecked.length) {
    filtered = filtered.filter(item => 
      colorChecked.includes(item.dataset.colors.split(" ")[0])
    );
 }
 if (sizeChecked.length) {
    filtered = filtered.filter(item => 
      sizeChecked.includes(item.dataset.colors.split(" ")[1])
    );
 }
 if (priceChecked.length) {
    filtered = filtered.filter(item => 
      priceChecked.includes(item.dataset.colors.split(" ")[2])
    );
 }
 if (categoryChecked.length) {
    filtered = filtered.filter(item => 
      categoryChecked.includes(item.dataset.colors.split(" ")[3])
    );
 }
 
 filterables.forEach(filterable => {
    if (filtered.includes(filterable)) {
      filterable.style.display = "block";
    } else {
      filterable.style.display = "none";
    }
  });
}

filterCheckboxes.forEach(checkbox => {
   checkbox.addEventListener('change', updateFilter);
});

updateFilter(); // initial filter based on default checkbox state
```

```html
<div>
    <h3>Color</h3>
    <label><input type="checkbox" class="filter-checkbox color-checkbox" value="red">Red</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" class="filter-checkbox color-checkbox" value="green">Green</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" class="filter-checkbox color-checkbox" value="blue">Blue</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h3>Size</h3>
    <label><input type="checkbox" class="filter-checkbox size-checkbox" value="small">Small</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" class="filter-checkbox size-checkbox" value="medium">Medium</label><label>
      <input type="checkbox" class="filter-checkbox size-checkbox" value="large">Large</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h3>Price</h3>
    <label><input type="checkbox" class="filter-checkbox price-checkbox" value="10">$10</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" class="filter-checkbox price-checkbox" value="20">$20</label><label>
      <input type="checkbox" class="filter-checkbox price-checkbox" value="30">$30</label>
  </div>
    <div>
    <h3>Category</h3>
    <label><input type="checkbox" class="filter-checkbox category-checkbox" value="a">A</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" class="filter-checkbox category-checkbox" value="b">B</label><label>
      <input type="checkbox" class="filter-checkbox category-checkbox" value="c">C</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <br>
    <hr>
    <h1>Filtered Result</h1>
    <div class="filterable" data-colors="blue large 30 b">Product One</div>
    <div class="filterable" data-colors="green small 10 a">Product Two</div>
    <div class="filterable" data-colors="red medium 20 c">Product Three</div>
    <div class="filterable" data-colors="red large 30 a">Product Four</div>
  </div>
```

A little bit more simplification, a single loop with a fairly complex `if`:

```js
function updateFilter() {
   const colorChecked = getCheckedValues(colorCheckboxes);
   const sizeChecked = getCheckedValues(sizeCheckboxes);
   const priceChecked = getCheckedValues(priceCheckboxes);
   const categoryChecked = getCheckedValues(categoryCheckboxes);

   filterables.forEach(filterable => {
     let [color, size, price, category] = 
       filterable.dataset.colors.split(" ");

     if (
      (colorChecked.length === 0 || colorChecked.includes(color)) &&
      (sizeChecked.length === 0 || sizeChecked.includes(size)) &&
      (priceChecked.length === 0 || priceChecked.includes(price)) &&
      (categoryChecked.length === 0 || categoryChecked.includes(category))
     ) {
      filterable.style.display = "block";
     } else {
      filterable.style.display = "none";
     }
   });
}
```

Comment: @AdamZ101 does this answer solved your issue?